# Which Software Architecture am I using? XAMPP, Apache, MySQL, PHP Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, system-architecture

I use XAMPP to host an Apache web server and a MySQL database. Most of the data processing is done on the user's mobile phone. After a certain activity, information of the user is sent to the web server. The PHP script checks if the data is already in the database, if it is, the data is sent to the Firebase Cloud Messaging Server, which in turn sends the data to the user.

I have read Informations about the different system architectures but could not find one that fits my case.

My question is, which system architecture am I using?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question.

Comment: It is important because this is a school project and I have to give an overview of the system architecture

Comment: Then provide that overview.  Tacking a name onto it doesn't sound like what you were asked to do.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer:  Client-server.  You have a client, you have a server, you have a school project, so there we go.

Longer answer:  "I'm using dimensional lumber and wood-screws to build my house.  What architecture am I using?"